# SD Card not mounted still it is showing that it is mounted?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I do not have any sd card in my phone but still when I am using

String state= Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        Toast.makeText(this, state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

it is showing mounted. Why so and how do I query to know whether the device has sd card mounted or not

Comment: ["Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer."](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState(java.io.File))

Comment: so how to know that sd card is inserted or not